# How to use CKEditor in JAVA

Tags: ckeditor, smartgwt

I need to create an inline editor form with a toolbar and autosave function. I tried to understand how CKEditor works without success. I also read the documentation but I didn't really understand.

How can I create a simple canvas with an editor inside it (+ toolbar)?

I work with smartgwt in JAVA.

Thanks

I tried something like that but it doesn't work.

```
Canvas inlineCKEditorCanvas = new Canvas();
inlineCKEditorCanvas.setHeight(200);
inlineCKEditorCanvas.setHeight(500);
CKEditor ckEditor = new CKEditor();
ckEditor.setHeight("100");
ckEditor.setWidth("500");
inlineCKEditorCanvas.addChild(ckEditor);
```